# Trying to display record if ALL records equal something in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using 3 tables for this, Part, PartDrawing and ShopDrawing. Basically I want to display all ShopDrawings where all their Parts are in stock. However each ShopDrawing has multiple PartDrawings that go with it so when I run my query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ShopDrawing.DrawingNo FROM ShopDrawing, PartDrawing, Part
WHERE ShopDrawing.DrawingNo = PartDrawing.DrawingNo
AND PartDrawing.PartNo = Part.PartNo
AND Part.InStock = 'YES';
```

It displays every single ShopDrawing because they all have at least one Part that is in stock. I only want want it to display the ShopDrawings where all the Parts that are needed for it are in stock, and I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to evaluate by not select data with `Part.InStock = 'NO'` rather than select data with `Part.InStock = 'YES'`

```
SELECT 
     ShopDrawing.DrawingNo 
FROM 
     ShopDrawing WHERE ShopDrawing.DrawingNo NOT IN
         (SELECT 
              PartDrawing.DrawingNo 
          FROM 
              PartDrawing LEFT JOIN Part ON PartDrawing.PartNo = Part.PartNo 
          WHERE 
              Part.InStock IS NULL
          GROUP BY PartDrawing.DrawingNo 
          HAVING COUNT(*)>0)
```

Comment: i like the idea, but I actually don't have any parts that are not in stock...I added that column when I was trying to make this SQL work, but it's actually not useful. Basically a shop drawing is made up of parts drawings. Then a part is made from a part drawing, so basically I want to select the shop drawings where all of the part drawings that go with it have had parts made.

Comment: In my parts drawing table there is a partNo column and if it has a partNo then that part is in stock and if it's blank in that column for that part drawing then the part hasn't been made yet and I wouldn't want to display that shop drawing even if other part drawings that go with do have partNos

Comment: So, you can left join `PartDrawing` and `Part`. If `Part.InStock` is null, it mean that PartDrawing is not in stok.

Comment: actually I was just able to change your code to make it work. I just changed the 2nd FROM to PartDrawing and the 2nd WHERE PartDrawing.PartNo IS NULL. Thanks a lot though I wouldn't have figured that out without your post!

Comment: Thanks to you too. I have also edited my post as your working code

Comment: actually i have another question, if I also want to narrow it down by saying and Part.AssemblyID = 'text' where would I put that part?

Comment: Do you mean that just show data if `All PartDrawing` in stock and `Part.AssemblyID equal to 'text'`?

Comment: try `Part.InStock IS NULL OR Part.AssemblyID <> 'text'`